# Predict Logic Exercise

Tags: predicate-logic

I have a question regarding Resolution and Substitution 
We are Given the following rules

```
∀x∀y(p(x,y)=>∃z q(x,y,z))
∃x∀y∀z(r(y,z) <=> q(x,y,z))
∀x∃y (¬p(x,y) => ∀z q(x,y,z))
```

The question is, Can we prove this Rule

```
∃w ∃x ∃y ∃z ( r(x,y) ∧ q(x,w,z))
```

and we have these choices

```
1.true
2.false
c.Sometimes
d.It depends on Skolem constants' values.
```

at the beginning I know I must start with

```
¬(∃w ∃x ∃y ∃z ( r(x,y) ∧ q(x,w,z)))
```

so it will become

```
∀w ∀x ∀y ∀z ¬(r(x,y) ∧ q(x,w,z))
∀w ∀x ∀y ∀z (¬r(x,y) V ¬q(x,w,z))
¬r(x,y) V ¬q(x,w,z)
```

and then I should convert the given rules into CNF so we will have the following rules

```
1-  ¬p(x,y) V q(x,y,f(x,y))
2-  ¬r(y1,z1) V q(C1,y1,z1)
3-  ¬q(C1,y2,z2) V r(y2,z2)
4-  p(x3,f(x3)) V q (x3,f(x3),z3)
5-  ¬r(x4,y4) V ¬q(x4,w4,z4)
```

the answer is true, but I cannot prove that I feel like I am stuck 
so what is the right way to solve this question and get the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a small correction: make sure to use a new skolem function if needed. So, you should get:

\begin{array}{ll}
1- & \neg p(x,y) \lor  q(x,y,f_2(x,y))\\
2- & \neg r(y_1,z_1) \lor q(c_1,y_1,z_1)\\
3- & \neg q(c_1,y_2,z_2) \lor r(y_2,z_2)\\
4- & p(x_3,f_1(x_3)) \lor q(x_3,f_1(x_3),z_3)\\
5- & \neg r(x_4,y_4) \lor \neg q(x_4,w_4,z_4)\\
\end{array}
Continue with:

\begin{array}{llll}
6. & q(x,f_1(x),f_2(x,f_1(x))) & (1,4) & [x/x_3,f_1(x)/y,f_2(x,f_1(x))/z_3]\\
7. & r(f_1(c_1),f_2(c_1,f_1(c_1))) & (3,6) & [c_1/x,f_1(c_1)/y_2, f_2(c_1,f_1(c_1))/z_2]\\
8. & \neg r(x,y_4) & (5,6) & [x/x_4,f_1(x)/w_4,f_2(x,f_1(x))/z_4]\\
9. & \bot & (7,8) & f_1(c_1)/x, f_2(c_1,f_1(c_1))/y_4]\\
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you for answering this but I am still wondering about step 6:(3,5)[c1/x4,y2/w4,z2/z4] I though this will lead us to ¬q(c1,c1,z2) because to remove r(y2,z2) with ¬r(x4,y4) we should use [y2/x4,z2/y4]  or am I missing something? if we have ¬q(c1,c1,z2) then 7 will be ¬p(c1,c1) and we will not be able to continue with 8 since we cannot use  c1/x3 and f2(c1)/c1 right?
please, could you explain more step 6 more?

Comment: @sumaia Oops, yes, you are right, I was looking at the wrong term! ... let me see if this is a quick fix ...

Comment: thank you for your help .. I appreciate that

Comment: @sumaia You did very good yourself to notice my first attempt did not work!! :)

Answer (score 3):

My Answer would be:

```
1-  ¬p(x,y) V q(x,y,f1(x,y))
2-  ¬r(y1,z1) V q(C1,y1,z1)
3-  ¬q(C1,y2,z2) V r(y2,z2)
4-  p(x3,f2(x3)) V q (x3,f2(x3),z3)
5-  ¬r(x4,y4) V ¬q(x4,w4,z4)
```

from `(1,4)` :

```
q (x3,f2(x3),z3) V q(x3,f2(x3),f1(x,f2(x3))) [x3|x ,f2(x3)|y]
```

then if we substitute `[f1(x,f2(x3))|z3]` we get:

```
6- q (x3,f2(x3),f1(x,f2(x3)))
7- ¬p(C1,y2) V r(y2,f1(C1,y2)) (1,3) [C1|x,y2|y,f1(C1,y2)|z2]
8- ¬r(x3,y4) (5+6) [x3|x4,f2(x3)|w4,f1(x,f2(x3))|z4]
9- q(C1,f2(C1),z3) V r(f2(C1),f1(C1,f2(C1))) (7,4) [C1|x3,f2(C1)|y2]
```

then if we try `(9,3)`:

```
r(f2(C1),z3)V r(f2(C1),f1(C1,f2(C1))) [f2(C1)|y2,z3|z2]
```

then we substitute `f1(C1,f2(C1))|z3` so we get:

```
10- r(f2(C1),f1(C1,f2(C1)))
```

finally:

```
11-⊥ (10,8)
```

Comment: thank you Miriam ..